# Complicated LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I followed keras lstm examples and can understand those. I understand the single lstm layer networks.

Now, I am trying to have something similar to the following,
[image]

I am confused as to how to get the output of the last lstm layer (out of 3) as input to the first layer in the next time (l2 in the diagram below)

```
model.add( keras.layers.Embedding( vocab_size, output_dim=64, input_length=t_steps ))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True ) )
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True ) )
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True ) )
```

Comment: I believe you need to switch to the [functional API](https://keras.io/models/model/) in order to be able to connect multiple models as shown in the paper.